# Transferring DNNdatabase from local to production

Tags: database, local, dotnetnuke, production

I creaed one dnn applicaiton, and the source is moved to production and also same as the database is also moved to production server, but i am getting the dotnetnuke error. I think there is a database not inserted correctly. 
Can you help me how to transfer the database from local to production..

Answer (score 1):

I would double check that your local and production site web.config have the same machine key and decription key all match

Other thing to check would be that the connection string is correct

One more thing would be to check permissions on the database

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL Delta](http://www.sqldelta.com/)